# I need my character to constantly move forward at the same speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how to make constant movement on z axis via character controller. I need my character to constantly move forward at the same speed

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this. One is to simply move the object along the z axis via code with no care for physics. this will hold a constant velocity in that direction. You can hopefully see how this type of approach could e expanded for all directions by swapping out the zPosChange float for a vector representing the direction you want to move in. This is a kinematic position update.

```
public float speed = 10;

void Update()
{
    float zPosUpdate = gameObject.transform.position.z
    zPosUpdate += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, zPosUpdate );
}
```

The other way is to use the unity physics system to add force to a rigidbody component. To do this you must first have added a rigidbody and a collider to the object you are controlling. Since we want constant velocity and not acceleration and deceleration I wouldn't recommend that unless you really need the object to be able to be affected physically by collisions. You would do similar to the example I've given here but instead of the transform position you would set the velocity on the rigidbody component.

Comment: It's much better to use vector arithmetic rather than extracting out the float and plonking it back in again.  Otherwise good.

Comment: I would normally say so too. Far more reusable. But I thought this made it more explicit what was happening for the example. Since they only need the one axis.

Answer (score 0):

The forward axis of your character: `transform.forward`

**Basic Solution** with `Transform`:

```cs
public float speed = 2f;

public void Update()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * (speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Relative movement with `Transform.Translate`;

---

```cs
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

---

Basic **Rigidbody** `velocity` Setter:

```cs
private Rigidbody rigidbody;
public void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
public void Update()
{
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Add Force to you character.

```
 character_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed* Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: This won't hold a constant speed though. If you do it in Start you may get loss of speed due to the rigidbody's friction settings or collisions. If you do it in Update you will get infinite acceleration.

Comment: What if i add time.deltatime with it

Comment: It will still constantly accelerate but slower. You would still be adding force every frame but it would be a much smaller amount. This would give you uniform acceleration but not uniform speed which is what was asked for.